# OSX Yosemite periodically loses DNS info for my server

Tags: dns, macos

I'm running OSX Yosemite as my development machine. I run a [VPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_server) for the product I'm developing at cursiveclojure.com. Every so often (3 times now over the last month or so) my Mac somehow gets into a state where it can't resolve that domain, even though it seems to work from elsewhere and the server is available. So right now:

```
~/d/riddley (master)> ping cursiveclojure.com
ping: cannot resolve cursiveclojure.com: Unknown host
~/d/riddley (master)> dig cursiveclojure.com  ANY +noall +answer
; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> cursiveclojure.com ANY +noall +answer
;; global options: +cmd
cursiveclojure.com. 10799   IN  MX  10 cursiveclojure.com.
cursiveclojure.com. 10799   IN  A   95.170.82.135
cursiveclojure.com. 10799   IN  TXT "v=spf1 a mx ip4:95.170.82.135 ip6:2a01:7c8:aab0:51f::1 -all"
cursiveclojure.com. 10799   IN  NS  rush.easydns.com.
cursiveclojure.com. 10799   IN  NS  nirvana.easydns.net.
cursiveclojure.com. 10799   IN  NS  motorhead.easydns.org.
cursiveclojure.com. 10799   IN  SOA dns1.easydns.com. zone3.easydns.com. 1411422284 43200 10800 1209600 10800
~/d/riddley (master)> ping 95.170.82.135
PING 95.170.82.135 (95.170.82.135): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 95.170.82.135: icmp_seq=0 ttl=48 time=300.551 ms
```

A friend has confirmed that the site works fine from elsewhere. The only solution I have found is to restart my machine, flushing the DNS caches with `sudo discoveryutil udnsflushcaches` doesn't seem to help.

Does anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

From time to time I have the same problem - specially with my own MX server.
More or less default DNS setup for this DNS entry.

Restart helps, but **disconnecting and reconnecting the network cable works** too.
You could also try to change your network location.

Every of these *solutions* suck, I know. But it's ATM the fastest one before figuring out the real problem (one of the thousands other problems that came with Yosemite).